# C++, array of objects, customize where they are stored in memory

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, allocation

Currently I working on a existing project (DLL ) which I have to extend.

For the transport through the DLL I have a struct for example 'ExternEntry'
and a struct which passes a array of it.

```
struct ExternEntry
{
  unsigned int MyInt;
  const wchar_t* Text;
}

struct ExternEntries
{
  const ExternEntry* Data;
  const unsigned int Length;

  ExternEntries(const ExternEntry* ptr, const unsigned int size)
    : Data(ptr)
    , Length(size);
  {
  }
}
```

In the existing project architecture, it will be the first time that a array is passed to the DLL callers. So the existing architecture doesn't allow arrays and if a struct is passed to a caller, normally there is a wrapper-struct for it (because of their str pointers).

Inside the DLL I need to wrap the ExternEntry so have a valid Text pointer.

```
struct InternEntry
{
  ExternEntry Data;
  std::wstring Text;
  inline const ExternEntry* operator&() const { return& Data }
  UpdateText() { Data.Text = Text.c_str(); }      
}

struct InternEntries
{
  std::vector<InternEntry> Data;

  operator ExternEntries() const
  {
    return ExternEntries(Data.data()->operator&(), Data.size());
  }
}
```

So the problem is, when the Caller received the ExternEntries and created a vector again:

```
auto container = DllFuncReturnInternEntries(); // returns ExternEntries

std::vector<ExternEntry> v(container.Data, container.Data + container.Length);
```

The first element is valid. All other elements are pointing to the wrong memory because in memory the InternEntry (with the wstring Text) is stored between the next InternEntry.

Maybe I'm wrong with the reason why this can't work.

```
[Data][std::wstring][Data][std::wstring][Data][std::wstring]
```

Caller knows just about the size of the [Data]
So the vector is doing the following:

```
[Data][std::wstring][Data][std::wstring][Data][std::wstring] 
  |       |       |
 Get     Get     Get
```

instead of

```
[Data][std::wstring][Data][std::wstring][Data][std::wstring]
  |                   |                   |
 Get                 Get                 Get
```

**Do I have any possibilities to customize how the vector stores InternEntry objects in memory?**
like Data,Data,Data ..anywhere else wstring,wstring,wstring

I hope I have explained my problem well

Comment: Just to be sure, is this DLL for communicating between two programs? It seems like the naming `ExternEntries` and `InternEntries` might imply a separate program running on the system...

Comment: There is a are c++ header and c# files which defines the extern structures (ExternEntry & ExternEntries).
In the DLL a wrapper structure (InternEntry & InternEntries) is used.

Comment: This probably has more to do with how you're interfacing c++ and c# than the actual code you've provided. You might consider adding the tag C# and including more details about that relationship. I.E. Are you compiling c++ to run c# code? Or are you wanting to do certain math in c++ and have *that* function call exported in the form of a DLL used by a C# application? (Note, I don't have much experience integrating C# and C++)

Comment: `ExternEntries` is not a POD type, as it contains a user-defined constructor.  So I am curious how you are able to define a C# interface to this type.

Comment: There is a c++/cli wrapper to use the c++ dll in c#. But this isn't the issue.
In C# or Delphi i can get the array of ExternEntry. Just ignore that this gonna be used in c# or somewhere else. The problem is that the pointer (ExternEntries.Data) which points to the first element of an array is valid. But if you wants to get the next element (ExternEntries.Data[1]) than the pointer is invalid, because it is part of the wrapped structure where is more than the struct size of ExternEntry.

Comment: It looks to me like you have a container of some sorts, but you haven't written an API for accessing the container. Do that (and, in particular, aim to have the API conform to C++'s Container concept), and you should be able to use it seamlessly.

Comment: You're assuming the caller receives an array of structs containing a `wstring`, whereas the structs actually each contain a `wchar_t *`.    Those are not the same things.